# Custom conditional compilation symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, conditional-compilation

I'm currently struggling using custom configurations.
My solution has one .NET Standard Library and two other Projects (one for Windows, one for Android) which uses the library.

What I try to do is giving the library the compiler constant WINDOWS and MOBILE.

Thats how I tried it several times:

1. Create two new configurations WindowsDE and MobileDE, copy settings from Debug configuration and create new project configuration. At some trys I also deleted the default Debug configuration but that didn't helped
2. Properties of the library -> Build, choose WindowsDE and put WINDOWS into Conditional compilation symbols field then choose MobileDE and put ANDROID in it.

I'm testing it with calling a method in the library :

```
#if WINDOWS
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Windows");
#endif

#if ANDROID
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Android");
#endif
```

But that doesn't work at all. Also just using

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("anything");
```

without having any #if does not print and at some trys I could not even debug the library anymore.

Would appreciate any help on this

Comment: "But that doesn't work at all" What does this mean? Any exception/error? Unexpected results? If the code isn´t executed it´s most likely because neither `WINDOWS` nor `ANDROID` are defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can  define conditional compiling constants in the project properties

[image]

```
#if WINDOWS
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Windows"); // NOT printed!
#endif

#if ANDROID
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Android"); // Printed!
#endif
```

You can enter several symbols separated by semicolons. Don't set them `true` or `false`. The ones that are listed are `true`. The missing ones are automatically `false`.

If neither the one nor the other prints, then possibly the solution does not compile and you are running an old code. Try to rebuild the solution.